# Ajax JSON application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm only able to append the first image in the `<li>`. I tried to use prepend rather than append, and it shows the last image only.

Can someone help me please?

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost/PHP/events.php',
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    type:'POST',
    data:$(this),
    dataType:'JSON',
    error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
        alert(strError);
    },
    timeout:60000,
    success:function(data){
        for(var i in data){
            $("#Images").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");                    
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a dump of the entire JSON string?

Comment: Check what your data returns and what is its length

Comment: Maybe your data has only one item

Comment: I think that `data:$(this)`,  is the problem. Try send one field or whole the form.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina it return 3 images, and this is what I have in my database. I have no problems with images I can display them without using `<li>`. But I need to display them in the `<li>`.

Comment: what is `$(this)`? ..That is never a data object for a request...is it a form? if so use `data:$(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

Into the success callback `function`, do this:

```
success:function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
       $("#Images").append("<li>"+ v +"</li>");                    
     })  
}
```

Comment: won't produce anything different than a `for` loop would. Is a synchronous operation so no closure issues

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({url:'http://localhost/PHP/events.php',
headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
type:'POST',
data:$(this),
dataType:'JSON',
success:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
    alert(strError);},
    timeout:60000,
    success:function(data){
    var html='';
        for(var i in data){
            html += '<li>' + data[i] + '</li>'

        }
    $("#Images").append(html);
    }
});
```

**UpDated** I don't under stand why there are two `success methods`

```
$.ajax({url:'http://localhost/PHP/events.php',
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    type:'POST',
    data:$(this),
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        var html='';
        for(var i in data){
           html += '<li>' + data[i] + '</li>'
         }
        $("#Images").append(html);
        },
    });
```

Comment: code only answers aren't very useful without an explanation. Also can't have 2 `success` properties in the same object

Comment: @charlietfl so what should I do then?

Comment: You really should explain why your answer would solve the problem. and what you did to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i; i<=data.length; i++){
        $("#Images").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");                    
    }
```

make sure about your data attribute name.